# is there a programmatic way of setting bios options

Tags: linux, bios

Is there a programmatic way to set bios settings for linux machines. I have to toggle multiple bios options and reboot machine repeatedly to do some performance measurements with different bios options.

Comment: Found this: http://serverfault.com/questions/498557/is-it-possible-to-change-bios-settings-from-linux the jury says possibly to no.

Answer (score 1):

If your system supports it, `IPMI` may be the solution.

This is a low level H/W based interface that a lot of vendors support.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface

It can work even if the system is plugged into A/C but is powered off. One of things you can [purportedly] do with it is change BIOS settings.

Within IPMI, there is something called a "Baseboard Management Controller" (BMC). One of the things a BMC can provide is KVM console redirection (video, mouse, keyboard).

Another option is to enable remote access in the BIOS and you can set up a serial console. Then, control it from another machine. Combining the two, IPMI lets you do the serial console across the LAN (aka a SOL console)

https://serverfault.com/questions/301413/change-bios-settings-on-supermicro-system-via-a-script

Here's a short one for Dell systems: http://serverascode.com/2012/10/16/dell-ipmi-bios.html From that, there's the command example:

```
ipmitool -I lanplus -H server1-ipmi -U root -P password sol activate
```